# python error IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python

Actually, I wanna drow multiline subplots in Python.

```
i,j=0
countries = ["china-2","South Korea-2"]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,(len(countries)+1)//2)
for country in countries:
    axs[i, j].plot(total_miu,linewidth=2,color='green')
    axs[i, j].plot(AR,linewidth=2,color='red')
    axs[i, j].plot(PR, linewidth=2,color='blue')
    axs[i, j].plot(IR*0.08, linewidth=2,color='purple')
    axs[i, j].set_title(country)
    if i == 0:
       i = 1
    else:
        i = 0
        j = j + 1
```

but it gives the error
axs[i, j].plot(total_miu,linewidth=2,color='green')

IndexError: too many indices for array
I cannot find the reason. Can you help me to solve the error?

Comment: You contradict your self in code you have written `axs[i,j].plot(total_miu,linewidth=2,color='green')` but in description you got error `axs[i, j-1].plot(total_miu,linewidth=2,color='green')` . please correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you consult the [documentation of matplotlib.pyplot.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html).

`subplots` has a parameter `squeeze`:

```py
matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, *, sharex=False, sharey=False, squeeze=True, subplot_kw=None, gridspec_kw=None, **fig_kw)
```

> squeeze: bool, default: True
>
> - If True, extra dimensions are squeezed out from the returned array of Axes:
>
>   - if only one subplot is constructed (nrows=ncols=1), the resulting single Axes object is returned as a scalar.
>   - for Nx1 or 1xM subplots, the returned object is a 1D numpy object array of Axes objects.
>   - for NxM, subplots with N>1 and M>1 are returned as a 2D array.
> - If False, no squeezing at all is done: the returned Axes object is always a 2D array containing Axes instances, even if it ends up being 1x1.

The length of `countries` is 2, which makes `ncols=1` and the `2 x 1` subplots is squeezed to a 1D object.

If you want to make the `axes` a 2D array, set `squeeze` to `False`.